# How do you debug wpf relativesource throwing errors on load?

Tags: wpf, exception, binding, listbox, relativesource

I'm working with a WPF dialog window that contains a `ListBox`. The list box can display both an 'icon' and 'list' view. To accomplish this, we used  `ListBoxItem` styles that are dynamically applied to the `ListBox`, as well as a pair of corresponding `ItemsPanelTemplate`s. As is, it displays beautifully. However, when loading this dialog we get a few dozen binding errors, such as the following:

System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=VerticalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'ListBoxItem' (Name=''); target property is 'VerticalContentAlignment' (type 'VerticalAlignment')

Our theory is that the styles and templates are loading before the `ListBox`, and failing to find the properties they are bound to using code such as:

```
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding 
        Path=VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
        AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
```

This seems to happen one or more times before the `ListBox` is initialized and the styles and templates are applied. After the dialog finishes initializing, the errors stop.

Has anyone encountered this before? Can anyone suggest a solution we may have overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was covered here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/db050ce6-d084-41ad-9a31-c01831687683

Supposed to be a "known" issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix here:

http://blog.jtango.net/2009/05/08/using-a-grid-as-the-itemspanel-for-a-listbox-in-wpf-binding-errors/

You set the style using `ItemContainerStyle` on the `ListBox`.